# In a kernel, what are "global constructors"?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel, c

I am a beginner developing kernels (though I have developed several Hello World programs in C and C++). I frequently see reference being made to **global constructors** (e.g., osdev https://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Global_Constructors), but I have not been able to find a clear definition or in it.

Could someone please guide me to the correct definition? I know they are called before the kernel, but I am having trouble understanding why.

The kernel of which I take the example, is this:
  https://github.com/AlgorithMan-de/wyoos/commit/7eb9f8a1d5089cf7587e553e601c42db34dc94a2

in the linker.ld file, have this code:

```
  .data  :
  {
  start_ctors = .;
  KEEP(*( .init_array ));
  KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )));
  end_ctors = .;

  *(.data)
  }
```

in the kernel.c file, have this code:

```
typedef void (*constructor)();
extern "C" constructor start_ctors;
extern "C" constructor end_ctors;
extern "C" void callConstructors()
{
  for(constructor* i = &start_ctors; i != &end_ctors; i++)
     (*i)();
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to add any other material you have read on the subject and wherein the term has been used.

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided has a clear definition:

> This tutorial discusses how to correctly invoke global constructors, such as those on global C++ objects. These are supposed to have run before your main function, which is why the program entry point is normally a function called _start.

In most OSs, there is a step where the process' memory is filled with its initial values.  For C code, that is typically sufficient.  However, sometimes you want to execute some code *before* `main()`, which is your official entry point.  For example, in C++, you need to be able to call the constructor of all global objects before `main()` is invoked.

To resolve this, and any other run-time activities which must be done before `main()`, each system provides some way to execute a function before main.  The article mentions that some treat it as a simple array of function pointers, but some compilers will obscure it and hide it.

The key takeaway is that these are handled before the *entry point* of your program.